# Toggle fade elements, fade out each on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem that I want to fade in the elements hidden within my li.

```
<li class="btn">One
    <div class="hidden">Hidden One</div>
</li>
<li class="btn">Two
    <div class="hidden">Hidden Two</div>
</li>
```

It works, but I want to be also able to hide either of the hidden elements when I click on it for the second time.
Please, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareksmakosz/rUUR2/2/).
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    var hidden = $(this).find('.hidden');
    $('.hidden').not(hidden).fadeOut();
    $(this).find('.hidden').fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rUUR2/3/)**

Comment: +1 I haven't answered one question today because of you! Go to sleep!!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the first line in your click handler to:

```
$('.hidden').not($(this).find('.hidden')).fadeOut();
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rUUR2/4/)

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    $('.hidden').not($(this).find('.hidden')).fadeOut();
    $(this).find('.hidden').fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: I gave you one up for this answer, since you answered my question as well :)